# How to find with data and sum of field

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

In my Project, I hava a data base table is like that[image]

This query in `JPQL query`
I have find `select c from SalesInvoice c where c.invoicedate BETWEEN :from AND :to` how to find sum of amount field.
I need find data field and summation of amount field one query

- In my javafx Project `tableview.setItem(query)` tableView will persist

Comment: Can you write down the expected output...

Comment: how to get summation and find output in one query @user3022109

Comment: Use Aggregate function SUM to find the sum and group by on the column which you want to find the sum...

Comment: Ok i will check @user3022109

Comment: `select sum(c.amount) from SalesInvoice c where c.invoicedate BETWEEN :from AND :to` would get you the sum for a given date range. You can then add a `group by` clause if you need to group it by `salestype` etc

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate function `SUM` to find the sum and `group by` on the column which you want to find the sum...